# Только бы / лишь бы в придаточных цели

Tags: синтаксис

> Ей хотелось выговориться, но она еще не была готова к откровениям с
>   первым встречным незнакомцем. Она увидела Патрика. Он мог бы ее
>   выслушать, **только бы он не действовал ей на нервы и ни о чем не
>   спрашивал**.

В интернете нашла инфо, что *только бы* и *лишь бы* "*употребляются при присоединении придаточной части сложноподчиненного предложения со значением цели (для достижения которой субъект главной части готов приложить максимум усилий)*". Понимаю, что в части **только бы он не действовал ей на нервы и ни о чем не спрашивал** выражается желательность с помощью *только бы* + формы на -*л*. Но не понимаю, почему это предложение надо считать целевым? Я не вижу там цель. Помогите понять, пожалуйста!

Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

В приведённом вами правиле нет утверждения об употреблении таких выражений *исключительно* при названных смыслах предложения (присутствие цели). В самом примере речь о цели, действительно, не идёт. Смысл высказывания в том, что дама готова доверить свои мысли знакомому (предполагает, что он мог бы её выслушать - возможно, он подходит для этого) и при этом возлагает надежды на то, что тот не будет задавать лишних вопросов - она немного опасается этого: *только бы* этого не было! При похожей структуре предложения и тех же выражениях (только бы, лишь бы) смысл может быть совершенно иным, и *цель* может иметь место:

> Он готов был ее выслушать, только бы она успокоилась и перестала бить
>   тарелки.

Здесь смысл в том, что он готов был её выслушать ради наступления  (**с целью** достижения) спокойствия.

Answer (score 2):

Ответ исправлен.

**Он мог бы ее выслушать, только бы он не действовал ей на нервы и ни о чем не спрашивал.**

**Смысл предложения:** Он мог бы ее выслушать (= подходит на эту роль),  если только он не будет действовать ей на нервы и  о чем-либо спрашивать.

Тогда это вариант СПП с придаточным **условия, а не цели**. Придаточная часть выражает условие, при котором может осуществиться ситуация в главной части.

*Похожий вариант из Нацкорпуса: Он **мог бы** простить Ляхова, ― о, он простил бы его с радостью, горячо и искренно, ― **но только, если бы** это было результатом его свободного выбора. [В. В. Вересаев. Два конца (1899-1903)]

*Примечание**

Сравнить: Она на всё была бы готова, только бы он ее выслушал (это СПП с придаточным **цели**).

Answer (score 2):

> Ей хотелось выговориться, но она еще не была готова к откровениям с
>   первым встречным незнакомцем. Она увидела Патрика...

С Патриком она была знакома, потому…

***...Он мог бы ее выслушать. Только бы он не действовал ей на нервы и ни о чем не спрашивал!***

Здесь два предложения. Во втором *только бы*  —  **частица**, выражающая желательность приведённых в этом предложении действий.

При объединении предложений (при замене точки на запятую) получим, по-моему, скорее не сложноподчинённое, а бессоюзное сложное предложение.